# What is the purpose of having a one-way function also be a permutation on it's on domain?

Tags: one-way-function

From a cryptographic sense, what value is added from setting the domain to be the image in the mapping?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-way permutation (OWP) is more structured than a one-way function, and hence a stronger object. This makes the task of constructing higher cryptographic objects from OWPs easier and also, at times, leads to more efficient constructions. For example, consider pseudo-random generators (PRGs): it is quite straightforward to construct a PRG from a OWP; but constructing a PRG from a OWF took a lot more effort -- you can read more [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs687/2006fa/lectures/lecture11.pdf).

Comment: Yes. But for small domain ( e.g $\{0,1\}^{256}$ ), a public OWP is much harder to construct than a public OWF. If one has such OWP, I want to know ! Thus [I asked](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/54079/555).

Comment: That's an interesting question!